# How to move Free space from One partition to another 100% Full Partition in Linux CentOS

Tags: linux, server, centos7, mount

We have a Linux CentOS server. Our 1 partition `"/dev/md3"` is 100% used. That's why Mongo DB is not being connected. Can someone let me know how to solve this issue. I think mounting the partition is the solution? But I also have to make sure that Data should not be destroyed.

The space details are the following. `"/dev/md3"` is the full and `"/dev/md4"` has 900 GB Free. We need to increase the space in `"/dev/md3"`. So our all services & Mongo DB should start working again.

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        65844948        0  65844948   0% /dev
tmpfs           65888636        0  65888636   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           65888636    10760  65877876   1% /run
tmpfs           65888636        0  65888636   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/md3        20026172 19997792         0 100% /
/dev/md2          498468    88837    379375  19% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1    522228     2660    519568   1% /boot/efi
/dev/md4       901136592   258420 855080032   1% /home
/dev/loop0        763700     1200    722872   1% /tmp
tmpfs           13177728        0  13177728   0% /run/user/0
```

Or is there any way to move Mongo DB to another partition with more space?

Comment: Downvote was probably from this being posted to the wrong StackExchange site.  This probably belongs at ServerFault, SuperUser, or a Linux SE site.  See: [tour] and   https://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: "How do I change MongoDB to use a new location" is probably a SuperUser question since it's application configuration not SQL programming, but that's just an opinion.  For that question a Google search might get you the fastest answer.

Comment: Ok I will post it in stackexchange serverfault website. Thanks.

Comment: @DaveS I was the one and you are right about the reason. Just my expectation was that a user with > 1k reputation could differentiate between SE sites.

Answer (score 1):

You can't move free-space. What you need to do is move some of the files on the / partition into the /home partition. (With out rebuilding the system)

It may be easiest to move the MongoDB itself, since that's the thing you want to be able to grow.

Comment: Can you please send any helping link or set of commands to run to move Mongo to another partition.